# How to access (edit and read) a shared with me google doc using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have been assigned a task which in most inner form is just updating a shared doc (whose owner is my friend) on google drive using javascript.

But I am completely clueless on this, All I know is i might have to use google app scripts, but can i use google app scripts for this? what are my options and how can I use app script with javascript?

Thank you and my apologies if this question sounded lame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. You need to choose between them, then do your research to understand each one. The two options are mutually exclusive, so once you choose one, you should ignore the other, otherwise you'll confuse yourself :-)

1. Use Google Apps Script. This is server-side Javascript and is decribed here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ and the Google Drive aspect is described here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/
2. Use the Drive SDK. Since you said Javascript, this will be using client-side Javascript. The top level doc is https://developers.google.com/drive/, plus you will need to understand OAuth https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Remember, as you are doing your research, make sure that you are only reading about option 1 or option 2.